# Heroku Deployment using Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm new to Heroku. I'd like to ask, can I deploy my rails 4 app without database in Heroku?
I'm trying to deploy now. But I'm always getting an error

```
at=error code=H10 
desc="App crashed" 
method=GET 
path="/favicon.ico" 
host=XXXXXX 
request_id=b98ff53f-13b7-432d-9b12-123011f6210b 
fwd="49.147.56.19" 
dyno= 
connect= 
service= 
status=503 
bytes=
```

Hoping that someone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly: **yes**, you can deploy your Rails app without a database; but it won't run

Since you're new, let me explain:

--

**Heroku**

Heroku runs on the [AWS cloud computing infrastructure](https://www.heroku.com/policy/security#data_centers). I'm not exactly *how* it does this, but every "dyno" you use is essentially an AWS "instance" (which is why [you get 750 dyno-hours for free](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing#750-free-dyno-hours-per-app) -- you get the *micro* instance for free)

This means that each time you push your application to Heroku, you're basically getting it pushed onto your own AWS instance, which will run regardless of whether you have a database or not.

Because Rails *relies* on database connectivity, even though your application can "reside" on the Heroku system, it doesn't mean you'll be able to access your data with it. And since Rails *needs* db connectivity to run, you'll typically find the application will crash if you don't have a database attached

--

**DB**

I don't why you'd ask whether you need a db or not, considering Heroku provides free access to their [PostgreSQL db infrastructure](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) (which, again, is hosted with AWS)

I would personally just set up a PostgreSQL db with Heroku to get things working, then adapt as you require.

---

## Errors

Some things you should be aware of in regards to errors on Heroku

There are *two types* of error that Heroku can serve:

**Heroku**

[image]

**Rails**

[image]

--

The difference between the two is important - a "Heroku" error basically means there's an issue with the Heroku system itself. A "Rails" error means the Rails application is running, but has a problem (probably with your code)

If you have a problem with Heroku, it typically means you have DB connection issues (as Rails requires DB connectivity). Rails issues are much more in-depth

To avoid either error, I'd highly recommend setting up a free PostgreSQL db on your Heroku instance, allowing you to rule out that issue, then proceed with further debugging

Comment: Application Error in Heroku i see on my browser. I dont have any idea what is my error. I just follow the step in Heroku Api.

Comment: You can type `$ heroku logs` in your CLI to bring back the logs - you should do this; but I'd recommend it's a DB error

Comment: I set up my rails without database. Because my database handle by Java interface that will sent an http to my rails app.

Comment: Can you explain further? I don't understand your methodology as to why you'd be using Java?

Comment: My Rails Application will get the data on Java Application(Interface Application). The Java application will the one will connect to our database that deploy on cloud server. Java Apps create an internal api for sending/recieving from my Rails App. Hope you understand

Comment: I think so - where are you hosting the Java app?

Comment: Its on Rackspace Cloud

Comment: Nice - we have Rackspace Cloud too!!!! Question - why are you using Heroku for Rails app, when your Java is on Rackspace? Why not just either make a new instance on RS or just use the same instance you have?

Comment: Its much easier to deploy Rails 4 on Rackspace withour database adaptor?

Comment: Yep - Heroku is PAAS - meaning it will actively look for a db adapter; whereas using your own stack will mean you can control how it works

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort to answer my question. I will study how to deploy my Rails app on Rackspace. Thank you again. You help me a lot.